# Global fields for nodes and blocks

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to move the site from WordPress to Drupal 8, but there is one very unpleasant problem that I have been trying to solve for several days. I really hope that you will help me find the right answer.

I have a website with an overview of old Russian coins, which shows their average market price in dollars. I need to create a **global field** where I could enter the current exchange rate of the ruble to the dollar. For example - 67.88 rubles for a dollar.

It is very important that this field is displayed in hundreds of nodes and in one block and as soon as I change the values of this field, it has changed everywhere on the site.

I want to achieve the following result:

```
{% set priceindollars = content.field_price.value %}
{% set exchangerouble = content.field_roubles.value %}
{% set convert = priceindollars*exchangerouble %}
{{ convert }}
```

I dug over the entire network and I understand that the question is complex and non-standard, but I still hope for help from your community.